# Upgrade facebookSDK from 4.7 to 4.35

Tags: android, facebook, debugging, jar

I'm facing the problem with updating facebook SDK from 4.7 to 4.35

> implementation 'com.facebook.android:facebook-android-sdk:4.35.0'

The error output is

> Cannot copy C:\Users\Tai\Downloads\Projects\karufx-android-renewal\app\build\intermediates\transforms\desugar\debug\138.jar to back up folder, build will continue but next time this file is modified will result in a cold swap.

and

> Unexpected inputs: ImmutableJarInput{name=com.parse.bolts:bolts-tasks:1.3.0, file=C:\Users\Tai\Downloads\Projects\karufx-android-renewal\app\build\intermediates\transforms\desugar\debug\133.jar, contentTypes=CLASSES, scopes=EXTERNAL_LIBRARIES, status=REMOVED}, ImmutableJarInput{name=com.parse.bolts:bolts-applinks:1.3.0, file=C:\Users\Tai\Downloads\Projects\karufx-android-renewal\app\build\intermediates\transforms\desugar\debug\131.jar, contentTypes=CLASSES, scopes=EXTERNAL_LIBRARIES, status=REMOVED}, ImmutableJarInput{name=com.facebook.android:facebook-android-sdk:4.10.0, file=C:\Users\Tai\Downloads\Projects\karufx-android-renewal\app\build\intermediates\transforms\desugar\debug\134.jar, contentTypes=CLASSES, scopes=EXTERNAL_LIBRARIES, status=REMOVED}, ImmutableJarInput{name=com.android.support:cardview-v7:23.4.0, file=C:\Users\Tai\Downloads\Projects\karufx-android-renewal\app\build\intermediates\transforms\desugar\debug\132.jar, contentTypes=CLASSES, scopes=EXTERNAL_LIBRARIES, status=REMOVED}

Look like it's missing some jar file in debug folder, can anyone help me please, tks in advance :D

Answer (score 0, accepted):

in my case, I am using like this

```
 implementation 'com.facebook.android:facebook-login:4.29.0'
```

it is working properly